# Object in Array, copy not reference

Tags: javascript

Here is what I have: particles is an array full of particle objects. Currently I just add references of the object to the array, so after the loop ends every object has the same velocity values. But I want different for each one.
What needs to be done, that there are actual objects in the array and not just references to the object?

```
for (i = 0; count > i; i++){
    var particle = this.model; //object i want to have multiple clonse from
    particle.velocity = vec3.create(); //vec3.create from glmatrix library
    var x = Math.random() * (0.1 - (-0.1)) + (-0.1); //value -0.1-->0.1
    var y = Math.random() * 0.1; //value 0-->0.1
    var z = Math.random() * (0.1 - (-0.1)) + (-0.1); //value -0.1-->0.1
    vec3.set(particle.velocity, x, y, z);
    this.particles.push(particle);
}
```

Comment: What is `this.model`?

Comment: Can you show the vec3 code?

Comment: You need to copy the objects. You may look for "deep cloning" or simply implement a specific cloning.

Comment: create a new particle on each iteration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment, you have only one object that you're repeatedly putting in the array: `this.model`. This line:

```
var particle = this.model;
```

doesn't *copy* `this.model`, it just uses a new variable to refer to it. Then each time you do

```
particle.velocity = vec3.create();
```

...you *overwrite* the previous loop's value on `particle.velocity`, which is also `this.model.velocity`, because `particle === this.model`.

It sounds like you want to *copy* `this.model`, rather than reusing it. How you do that will depend a lot on `this.model`. Here's a naive way:

```
function shallowCopy(source) {
    var key, dest = {};
    for (key in source) {
        dest[key] = source[key];
    }
    return dest;
}
```

then

```
var particle = shallowCopy(this.model);
```

...but again, it depends a lot on what `this.model` is. If `this.model` has properties that refer to other objects, the above reuses those objects; you'd need a "deep" cloning function to make copies of those.

It's likely what you really want, rather than cloning, is a *constructor function*:

```
function Model() {
    // Set up basic properties and such on `this`, e.g.
    this.foo = "bar";
}
```

then

```
var particle = new Model();
```

Comment: A constructor definitely sounds like the requirement.